# Uploading files to dropbox with XAMPP PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, xampp, dropbox-api

I am trying to upload files to dropbox. I am on Windows and using XAMPP. This is what I have.

```
# Include the Dropbox SDK libraries
require_once "dropbox-sdk/Dropbox/autoload.php";

use \Dropbox as dbx;

$appInfo = dbx\AppInfo::loadFromJsonFile("../view/configs/json_config.json");
$webAuth = new dbx\WebAuthNoRedirect($appInfo, "MyApp");

$authorizeUrl = $webAuth->start();

echo "1. Go to: " . $authorizeUrl . "\n";
echo "2. Click \"Allow\" (you might have to log in first).\n";
echo "3. Copy the authorization code.\n";

//   $fp=fopen("php://stdin", "r");
//   $in=fgets($fp,4094);
//   fclose($fp);
define('STDIN',fopen("C://xampp/php/php.exe", "r"));
if (PHP_OS == 'WINNT') {
  echo '$ ';
$line = trim(fgets(STDIN)); // reads one line from STDIN
//$line = stream_get_line(STDIN, 1024, PHP_EOL);
//$read = str_replace("\r\n", "", $in);
} 
else {
//$line = readline('$ ');
$line = str_replace("\n", "", $in);
}


//$authCode = \trim(\readline("Enter the authorization code here: "));

list($accessToken, $dropboxUserId) = $webAuth->finish($line);
print "Access Token: " . $accessToken . "\n";

$dbxClient = new dbx\Client($accessToken, "MyApp");
$accountInfo = $dbxClient->getAccountInfo();

print_r($accountInfo);

$f = fopen("working-draft.txt", "rb");
$result = $dbxClient->uploadFile("/working-draft.txt", dbx\WriteMode::add(), $f);
fclose($f);
print_r($result);

$folderMetadata = $dbxClient->getMetadataWithChildren("/");
print_r($folderMetadata);

$f = fopen("working-draft.txt", "w+b");
$fileMetadata = $dbxClient->getFile("/working-draft.txt", $f);
fclose($f);
print_r($fileMetadata);
```

which I found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/php)

Now I am already having problems trying to execute this code as this code originally uses the readline function (or library) which is not supported on windows. I found a substitute that I am trying to use but it doesn't work.

Currently, this is the error I am getting:

"Uncaught exception 'Dropbox\Exception_BadRequest' with message ' in ....\RequestUtil.php on line 251."

I have no idea how to get this working. Has anyone done this successfully on windows using XAMPP?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error here makes sense... it looks like your code tries to read the contents of `php.exe`, which doesn't sound like a good idea. :-) That's why the string is "... This program cannot be run in DOS mode."

But if you don't redefine STDIN, `$line = trim(fgets(STDIN))` looks reasonable. What happens when you run that?

Comment: It says use of undefined constant STDIN.

Comment: How about `$stdin=fopen("php://stdin", "r"); $line = trim(fgets($stdin)); fclose($stdin);`? BTW, how are you running the script? I assume from the command line?

Comment: I have no idea how to run the script. Can you help me with it?
with $stdin=fopen("php://stdin", "r"); $line = trim(fgets($stdin)); the page just doesn't load. It gets hanged.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to run this in a web browser, but it's a command-line app. Try "php <script name>.php" from a command prompt.

Comment: but I need it as a web app.

Comment: Then you should probably start with an example of a web app. The PHP SDK ships with a file browser sample that's a web app.

Comment: I am using XAMPP on windows. Where can I find that sample?
Also, what I ultimately need to achieve is being able to upload files to dropbox on a button click. Can this be done with console app/command prompt?

Comment: The sample comes with the PHP SDK. It's in the "examples" directory. "A button click" on your local computer or in the browser? The former could be a command-line tool, but the latter would need to be a  web app.

Answer (score 0):

It's throwing an exception because there is something wrong with your request to DropBox.

To get more debugging information, place **all** of your DropBox method calls within a try/catch block, for example:

```
try
{
  $authorizeUrl = $webAuth->start();
}
catch (dbx\WebAuthException_BadRequest $e) {
  var_dump($e); // Will returned detailed information about the error
}
```

this should start you on the right track in determining the cause.